# Не запускается Django через PyCharm(через консоль запускается)

Tags: python-3.x, django, pycharm

Есть простейшее Django-приложение , которое корректно работает на удаленном сервере, в связке с БД MySql.

При запуске сервера командой `python3 manage.py runserver` через терминал, сервер запускается корректно и без ошибок. Однако, если запускать сервер через PyCharm, выводит следующую ошибку:

```
ssh://miks@111.111.111.111:21/home/miks/DJ/venv/bin/python3 -u /home/miks/DJ/server/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f1f8ef2b6a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Но mysqlclient на сервере установлен, в противном случае была бы соответствующая ошибка при запуске Django через терминал

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm использует неверную среду python. Вы можете изменить интерпретатор проекта в настройках:

**File**-> **Settings**
В всплывающем меню: **Project**-> **Project Interpreter**-> **add or create virtualenv environment**

Comment: В том то и дело, что виртуальное окружение для Django в Pycharm настроено (это можно видеть, если внимательно посмотреть на Traceback: File "/home/miks/DJ/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb') Однако, в данном виртуальном окружении mysqlclient установлен